# EGit and Git Bash not syncing up

Tags: git, github, egit, git-bash

I'm a novice when it comes to Git Bash, but comfortable enough in a CLI environment.
I'm using the eclipse plugin EGit for committing my work and pulling contributors work.

My problem is that sometimes if 2 of us have been working on the same file we get conflicts, now sometimes this can be solved in Egit by doing a merge and sometimes I have to go into the CLI to try and fix it.

At the moment While I'm in Eclipse I'm up to date, my working tree has been uploaded to git properly, all is right with the world. But if I then open Git Bash It tells me that I have "changes not staged for commit" Bash is lying to me, the changes have been successfully committed through EGit.

I have tried, stashing the changes and then clearing my stash, I've tried doing a checkout --, I've tried doing a git clean and added -f command, all without success.

So if someone could tell me: 
A. why is Bash not in sync with EGit?
B. How do I remove the "changes not staged for commit"
C. what is the best practice for avoiding conflicts, e.g. should we work on different branches?
D. When conflicts do occur what is the best practice/commands for resolving the issues?

As a note. I also have the Github windows application installed, The unstaged commits also appear in here and sometimes I use this program to resolve issues, but try to use it as little as possible, as I want to be a git bash wizard someday.

Comment: Just to be sure, what `git config core.autocrlf` return?